# How to import got in typescript?

Tags: typescript, node.js-got

i'm trying to import got from 'got'  in my typescript program to convert an url to a streamable file, but I tryed to import it in different ways and i obtaining always errors like :  `can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag`

my question is how can I import got correctly without get errors ?
Or is there another way to convert an url to a streamable file in typescript?

```
import { sha256 } from 'js-sha256';
import {Metadata} from './metadata';
import * as fs from 'fs'
const pinataSDK = require('@pinata/sdk');
import got from 'got';
export const ARC3_NAME_SUFFIX = "@arc3"
export const ARC3_URL_SUFFIX = "#arc3"
export const METADATA_FILE = "metadata.json"
export const JSON_TYPE = 'application/json'
export const JSONObject = "metadata.json"
export function asaURL(cid: string): string { return ipfsURL(cid)+ARC3_URL_SUFFIX }
export function ipfsURL(cid: string): string { return "ipfs://"+cid }
```

Comment: I am not sure about the solution but it may be dependent on the "module" settings in tsconfig.

Comment: "esModuleInterop" is still on true in the tsconfig

Answer (score 10):

Had the same problem with Version got@^12.0.0.

Downgraded to got@11.8.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add this option to your tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop

This is needed because CJS exports and MJS exports are out of box incompatible (because CJS has no notion of a default export, but MJS does).

Enabling this interop allows TS to import CJS dependencies into its modules.

---

If people are still struggling with this, [try using `xnr`](https://github.com/tbjgolden/xnr) to run your source code, I created it pretty much for this purpose as interop between TS, modules and npm packages can be pretty nasty and sometimes you want something that just works! :)

Comment: my configuration is already like this, but I still get error

Comment: could you add the ways you're currently trying to import it to your question?

Comment: I edited, everything works correctly the only import that creates problems is got

Comment: have you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes, npm version 6.14.15